# OpenCV (Python) order of added trackbars

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I'm building a track bar window with multiple sliders like so:

```python
import cv2

def do_nothing(_):
    pass

# Create window and add track bars
window_name = 'level control'
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)

for i in xrange(10):
    cv2.createTrackbar(str(i), window_name, 1, 10, do_nothing)

# Wait for escape key
while (True):
    k = cv2.waitKey() & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
```

The trouble is that they are added in a really strange order:

[image]

I was trying to work out the pattern, so I added them one by one. At each step they look like:

- 0
- 0 1
- 0 1 2
- 3 1 2 0 <- WHAT?
- 3 1 4 2 0
- 3 1 4 2 0 5
- 3 4 0 5 1 6 2

I can't figure out the pattern, but it's the same every time, so it's not random! Also the order that I add them in doesn't make a difference, so it seems to be based on the name. It's not alphabetical though, replacing the numbers with characters gives a similar order (e.g. `d b c a`). Is this a bug? Am I doing something funny? Is there a way to get my sliders to be in the order I want?

Comment: This is weird I tried your code and is working fine.. What OpenCV version you got?. I got 2.4.8

Comment: That is weird.. I'm using 2.4.8.2. Also, I'm running Python 2.7.6 on OSX 10.8.5.

Comment: Same python here, 2.7.6 and Ubuntu 14.04. Can I see the rest of your code?

Comment: Still works with full code.

Comment: I have the same.. Anyone found a solution?

Comment: Try upgrade to the latest version. Using 3.7.4 works